# 2012 VW Jetta SE battery cables hooked up wrong

Tags: electrical, battery, vw, jetta

my boyfriend hooked the jumper cables up backwards the electric systems lit up then went black and something started to smoke near the battery we have since had trouble with the battery keeping power so we replaced it and the alternator and bypassed the fusable link til the one i ordered comes in the mail what else could it have messed up

Comment: Any of the electrical components - test and see.

Comment: Add a photo of the thing that started to smoke.